# Average not calculating in nested for loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, average

I'm pretty stumped on this problem. My totaldistance is not calculating correctly. I'm not sure if this is because I set my loop up incorrectly or if I'm doing something else wrong. I'm getting an average of `-0` each time. I printed `printf(" total distance = %lf , dailyflights = %d\n", totaldistance, dailyflights);` before the average calculation to determine that it was the `totaldistance` that isn't calculating correctly and not the average.

An example of the desired output:

```
How many days has your dragon been practicing?
3

How many flights were completed in day #1?
2
How long was flight #1?
10.00
How long was flight #2?
15.00
Day #1: The average distance is 12.500.

How many flights were completed in day #2?
3
How long was flight #1?
9.50
How long was flight #2?
12.00
How long was flight #3?
13.25
Day #2: The average distance is 11.583.

How many flights were completed in day #3?
3
How long was flight #1?
10.00
How long was flight #2?
12.50
How long was flight #3?
15.00
Day #3: The average distance is 12.500.
```

my code:

```
//pre-processor directives
#include <stdio.h>

//Main function
int main()
{
    int days = 0, totaldays, flight_num, dailyflights;
    double distance, cur_distance = 0, totaldistance = 0, average_dist;

    printf("How many days has your dragon been practicing?\n");
    scanf("%d", &totaldays);

    for(days=1; days <= totaldays; days++) {
        printf("How many flights were completed in day #%d?\n", days);
        scanf("%d", &dailyflights);

        for (flight_num=1; flight_num <= dailyflights; flight_num++) {
            printf("How long was flight #%d?\n", flight_num);
            scanf("%ld", &distance);
            totaldistance = distance + totaldistance;
        }
        printf(" total distance = %lf , dailyflights = %d\n", totaldistance, dailyflights); /*I printed this line to determine what isn't correct and I determined that totaldistance is not calculating correctly*/
        average_dist = totaldistance / (float) dailyflights;
        printf("Day #%d: The average distance is %.3f.\n", days, average_dist);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to set `totaldistance` to zero before the start of each inner loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `%lf` instead of `%ld` to read the value of `double` to `distance` with `scanf`.

You should use `%f` instead of `%lf` to **printing** values of `double` with `printf` since `float` value is automatically expanded and there are no needs to distinguish between them.

Also, before the inner loop, you need to set `totaldistance = 0.0;` so that you accumulate each day's flights separately from each other day's flights to get the average distance computation correct.

Comment: Those are good points, but only part of the problem.  The code also needs to set the `totaldistance` to `0.0` before the start of the inner loop.

Comment: Thank you! That solved the average calculations for all the whole numbers. I'm still getting an error for decimal numbers. The program is interpreting 10+12.5+15 as 10+12+5+15 and thus giving me the wrong averages for any days that have flights with decimals in them. Edit combined with Jonathan's suggestion of setting the totaldistance to 0 solved the problem

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you! That solved my final issues. Can you explain why resetting totaldistance to 0 is needed because I was really stumped on this.

Comment: @tonomon: When you don't reset `totaldistance` to zero, you add the second day's distances to the sum of the first day's distances, and then divide by the number of flights on the second day, which is completely the wrong calculation, of course.